# Python [pydantic] - Date validation

Tags: python, mongodb, date, pydantic

i'd like to valid a json input for dates as pydantic class,
next , to simply inject the file to Mongo .

Simple class with date type

```
class CustomerBase(BaseModel):
    birthdate: date = None
```

Using motor for working with Mongo

Db configuration :

```
from motor.motor_asyncio import AsyncIOMotorClient

DB = DB_CLIENT[CONF.get("databases", dict())["mongo"]["NAME"]]
```

8/03/2021 - Update:

I did the following debug test,
first print the class to see how it saved and next try to inject it to Mongo.

so for input:

```
{ "birthdate": "2021-03-05"}
```

Routing:

```
@customers_router.post("/", response_model=dict)
async def add_customer(customer: CustomerBase):
    print(customer.dict())

>> {'birthdate': datetime.date(2021, 3, 5)}

    await DB.customer.insert_one(customer.dict())
    return {"test":1}

>> 
 File "./customers/routes.py", line 74, in add_customer
    await DB.customer.insert_one(customer.dict())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 698, in insert_one
    self._insert(document,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 613, in _insert
    return self._insert_one(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 602, in _insert_one
    self.__database.client._retryable_write(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1498, in _retryable_write
    return self._retry_with_session(retryable, func, s, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1384, in _retry_with_session
    return self._retry_internal(retryable, func, session, bulk)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1416, in _retry_internal
    return func(session, sock_info, retryable)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 590, in _insert_command
    result = sock_info.command(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 699, in command
    self._raise_connection_failure(error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 683, in command
    return command(self, dbname, spec, slave_ok,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 120, in command
    request_id, msg, size, max_doc_size = message._op_msg(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/message.py", line 714, in _op_msg
    return _op_msg_uncompressed(
bson.errors.InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: datetime.date(2021, 3, 5), of type: <class 'datetime.date'>
```

Issues:
1.The date in class saved as birthday: datetime.date(2021, 3, 5)
is that expected?
2.Surely the problem coming from :
'''
DB.customer.insert_one(customer.dict())
'''
it does work when i change the date type to str in Class

**Update  09/03/2022:**

following Tom's suggestion:
the decorator and parse_birthday function added.
Now i able to document to Mongo but not able to read it.

```
class CustomerBase(BaseModel):
    birthdate: datetime.date

    @validator("birthdate", pre=True)
    def parse_birthdate(cls, value):
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(
            value,
            "%d/%m/%Y"
        ).date()

    def dict(self, *args, **kwargs) -> 'DictStrAny':
        for_mongo = kwargs.pop('for_mongo', False)
        d = super().dict(*args, **kwargs)
        if for_mongo:
            for k, v in d.items():
                if isinstance(v, datetime.date):
                    d[k] = datetime.datetime(
                        year=v.year,
                        month=v.month,
                        day=v.day,
                    )
        return d

class CustomerOnDB(CustomerBase):
    id_: str
```

assign data (working):
input : {"birthdate": "01/11/1978"}

```
@customers_router.post("/", response_model=dict )
async def add_customer(customer: CustomerBase):

    customer_op = await DB.customer.insert_one(customer.dict(for_mongo=True))
    if customer_op.inserted_id:
        #customer_op.inserted_id -> is the str _id
        await _get_customer_or_404(customer_op.inserted_id)
        return { "id_": str(customer_op.inserted_id) }
```

When trying to read:

```
def validate_object_id(id_: str):
    try:
        _id = ObjectId(id_)
    except Exception:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400)
    return _id


@customers_router.get(
    "/{id_}",
    response_model=CustomerOnDB
)
async def get_customer_by_id(id_: ObjectId = Depends(validate_object_id)):
    customer = await DB.customer.find_one({"_id": id_})
    if customer:
        customer["id_"] = str(customer["_id"])
        return customer
    else:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Customer not found")
```

Getting:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 126, in serialize_response
    raise ValidationError(errors, field.type_)
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for CustomerOnDB
response -> 0 -> birthdate
  strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime (type=type_error)
```

Comment: You say you want to validate `dd/mm/yyyy` and give an example with `yyyy-mm-dd`. So which is it?

Comment: Your error message references bson, which is not mentioned anywhere else in your question.  Can you please give a [mcve] that shows your problem?

Comment: @jwodder -u right , the error coming from bson , main post updated with more details

Comment: @TomWojcik - actually it is not working with both , prefer using dd/mm/yyyy format.

Comment: Yes, it does. Show what doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your question is as your `CustomerBase` works fine with

`{ "birthdate": "2021-03-05"}`
this input.

If you want to parse `%d/%m/%Y` date, parse it using validator and [`pre`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/#pre-and-per-item-validators) parameter.

```
class CustomerBase(BaseModel):
    birthdate: date

    @validator("birthdate", pre=True)
    def parse_birthdate(cls, value):
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(
            value,
            "%d/%m/%Y"
        ).date()
```

EDIT:
You added a comment mentioning something else that doesn't work as you expect. AFAIK mongo doesn't accept `datetime.date`. Just change it to `datetime.datetime` when dumping to dict or change type to `datetime`.

example

```
import datetime

from pydantic.main import BaseModel


class CustomerBase(BaseModel):
    birthdate: datetime.date

    def dict(self, *args, **kwargs) -> 'DictStrAny':
        d = super().dict(*args, **kwargs)
        for k, v in d.items():
            if isinstance(v, datetime.date):
                d[k] = datetime.datetime(
                    year=v.year,
                    month=v.month,
                    day=v.day,
                )
        return d
```

If you need both functionalities

```
import datetime

from pydantic import validator
from pydantic.main import BaseModel


class CustomerBase(BaseModel):
    birthdate: datetime.date

    @validator("birthdate", pre=True)
    def parse_birthdate(cls, value):
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(
            value,
            "%d/%m/%Y"
        ).date()

    def dict(self, *args, **kwargs) -> 'DictStrAny':
        for_mongo = kwargs.pop('for_mongo', False)
        d = super().dict(*args, **kwargs)
        if for_mongo:
            for k, v in d.items():
                if isinstance(v, datetime.date):
                    d[k] = datetime.datetime(
                        year=v.year,
                        month=v.month,
                        day=v.day,
                    )
        return d


>>> c = CustomerBase(**{"birthdate": "03/05/2021"})
>>> c.dict()
>>> {'birthdate': datetime.date(2021, 5, 3)}
>>> c.dict(for_mongo=True)
>>> {'birthdate': datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 3, 0, 0)}
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, so when it comes to Mongo it looks that I need both the function for datetime.date converted to datetime.datetime and also need the decorator for handling the format? is there a way to include the date  format handling inside the def dict()?

Comment: `validator` is running when you want to load a dictionary into a `pydantic` object, and `dict()` method when you create an input for Mongo (from `pydantic` object to `dict`). So no, there's no way of combining them into a single method. But there's no problem in having both.

Comment: strange ,where is the weakness point?fastapi should do the required adjustment to work with Mongo?asking it as in many times there's need preform db query based on dates it make thing really complexity ,now I have problem with response_model=CustomerBase and the return object have the different datatype (hopefully u get my point)

Comment: No, web framework is for web stuff, pydantic for types stuff. You should change `birthdate` type to `datetime.datetime`.

Comment: Tom , changing birthday type to datetime.datetime will required user insert birthday in complex format  ,is that what u mean ?or it will required validtor?

Comment: in `parse_birthday` don't call `date()` so it returns date with time and change type of birthdate to `datetime.datetime`.

Comment: Tom ,not sure what u mean for date()  in parse_birthday  as there's no call for date().
I update main post with changes and issue raised on fetching back the data from Mongo ,
Seems such a headache for very trivial thing :(

Comment: I open a new post as solution suggested not worked for me , thanks Tom appreciate ur help